# How to enable Subscribed Calendar to be in read/write mode?

Tags: macos, ical, calendar

As today, any Subscribed Calendar is added as **Read Only** to the iCal Application

to confirm that. just double click in a day with the subscribed calendar selected and you will get this annoying popup message

[image]

**What should I do to enable read/write mode** into the subscribed calendar, as it supports both ways (I created the URL and works great with [Thunderbird w/Lightning](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/lightning))

**Problem also comes** that in iPad/iX happens the same situation, and **all I wanted was to be able to create and edit events** to by calendar

Comment: Is this a CalDAV calendar? Or just an .ics file on a server somewhere? (WebDAV?)

Comment: the file in CalDAV is an iCal format, so .ics. Right now it's a web server that reads Http Methods such as `PROPFIND` and `PUT` and delivers an iCal file.

Answer (score -2):

The owner grants & controls read / write access. You'd have to ask who owns the calendar.

Comment: you're quite arrogant aren't you? iCal WebDav is enabled for Read and Write, but iCal App does not do it, if you use Mozilla Thunderbird with Lightning, you will see you are able to edit **ANY** Subscribed URL !!!

Comment: No, This isn't about being arrogant. This is about being factually accurate. If I were to make a cal on google, made it public & gave the public read only access. You could subscribe to it, but you couldn't "edit" anything on it. You could copy the event or item to your cal & change it? But that isn't editing the calendar item itself. It's editing your copy of an item. If you changed something on that copy it doesn't mean that everyone else subscribing automatically get's your changes. Perhaps you've only had access to read / write cal's before?